# Simulate KM curves with assumptions in R

Tags: r, survival, simulation

I am looking to simulate 2 survival curves under different assumptions on the mean / median process underlying the 2 arms. Has anyone done this in R?

Comment: Be aware that asking for code is off-topic. Questions about simulating survival data can be on-topic, though. You will have to say a lot more for this question to be answerable. What distributions are you considering? Are you thinking of censoring? What kind? How much? What are the assumptions you need to make? What is the point of the simulation? Etc.

Comment: Considering exponential / weibull. Right censoring, 5-20%. Say for example that group A has median 6 month survival and group B has median 8 month survival.

Also - why is code off topic? Is that for stack?

Comment: Please put the additional information in your question.

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic for SO as well. The additional information helps. Can you clarify what your question is now?